# EmberJS unable to find view exception

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I got problem with EmberJS I can't understand

The problem could be found in the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wLKKQ/

JS :

```
var fileUploader = [] || fileUploader;
fileUploader.app = Em.Application.create();

fileUploader.app.userDetailsView = Em.View.create({
    clientIP: null
});​
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
        {{#view fileUploader.app.userDetailsView}}
            <h2>Hello Guest, your IP is: {{clientIP}}</h2>
        {{/view}}
    </script> 
    <script>
        $(function () {
            fileUploader.app.userDetailsView.set('clientIP', '::1');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Unable to find view at path 'fileUploader.app.userDetailsView'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems in your code.

- Ember.Application should be in an uppercase namespace (see [The Emberist blog](http://www.emberist.com/2012/04/09/naming-conventions.html)).
- You must pass a view class to the #view helper, not an instance (you consequently have to replace `Ember.View.create` with `Ember.View.extend`.
- Your script that edit the `clientIP` does not work, because now `FileUploader.app.userDetailsView` is a class. You can do the same thing with `didInsertElement` Ember.View method.
- In your template, you have to specify `view.clientIP`, according to [View Context Changes](https://gist.github.com/2494968).

Now [this JSFiddle work](http://jsfiddle.net/rNTde/) :

```
FileUploader = [] || fileUploader;
FileUploader.app = Em.Application.create();
FileUploader.app.userDetailsView = Em.View.extend({
    clientIP: null,

    didInsertElement: function() {
        this.set("clientIP", "::1");
    }
});​
```

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
      {{#view FileUploader.app.userDetailsView}}
         <h2>Hello Guest, your IP is: {{view.clientIP}}</h2>
      {{/view}}
    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```